# What word means 'discrete piece of knowledge'?

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

In my understanding 'knowledge' is one of a group of nouns in English that is characterized as uncountable (meaning 'knowledge' should never be made plural).

If that is the case, is there a word in English that describes the concept of individual bits of known material that can be made plural?

In other words, if knowledges is incorrect (although there is apparently some debate over that), what can be used in its place?

Edit 1: So there has been a decent amount of input so far and I felt like I should clarify one thing. The concept I need to capture is more than just information or data. Those are more related to trivia and facts. The word I am looking for is a countable noun that encompasses more than a physical skill that can be trained and observed. It is more than a list of facts. It needs to contain the concept of a body of information that can be used for extrapolation. For instance, naming the individual pieces of an engine is facts or data; understanding how they interplay and how that can assist in troubleshooting is knowledge; being able to repair a cracked head is a skill. The first example (fact, datum) and the last (skill) are countable, knowledge is not. So if I have knowledge of a group of separate topics I have knowledges. If this doesn't actually clarify anything, please let me know.

Comment: Is this for a particular context?

Comment: *a piece of knowledge* is idiomatic.

Comment: @amt528 For instance 'Running a machine shop is a complex task. It requires a person to have a variety of skills and knowledges.' In this case 'knowledges' is intended to be the various bits and chunks of information that a person would need. Skills are things like using specific tools in the correct manner. Knowledges would be things like which oil is best for which machine, temperatures at which metals lose temper, how to manage accounts receivable, etc.

Comment: I think you'd just say "a high degree of skill and knowledge," or "a variety of skills and wide range of knowledge."  I don't think you'd ever try to break down knowledge into countable parts, at least not idiomatically.

Comment: I would call those ***facts*** (to answer the question in the OP main body: *a word in English that describes the concept of individual bits of known material that can be made plural*)

Comment: In your machine shop example they would be ***details***.  It requires a person to have a variety of skills and know a lot of [little] details.

Comment: @Jim in the context of machine learning, **facts** is exactly precise. +1

Comment: If it's a basic knowledge, consider **rudiments**.

Comment: One needs to know a lot more than facts, details or rudiments to know how to run a machine shop.  "variety of skills and wide range of knowledge" is good.

Comment: *Facts, skills, knacks* and *nuggets* could all fit in certain cuircumstances, but probably no situation fits more than one.  In what context are you asking?

Comment: _Bit_ is the definitive word. It's as discrete as anything can get.

Comment: Stop scratching your head as someone who has painted himself into a corner, and stick an adjective in front of *knowledge*, perhaps "extensive".

Comment: 'Knowledges' is acceptable as a word, but the count noun is rare and even more rarely used to refer to data bits. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knowledge): **knowledge** noun 6
(countable) Something that can be known; a branch of learning; a piece of information; a science. [from 16th c.]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Bacon is not so far back as to not be valid. So at least an argument can be made that 'knowledges' is not improper. Could you add that as an answer? Perhaps framing it as an argument against MS Word and other sources that list 'knowledge' as an uncounted noun?

Comment: @TimRomano No, no. I was painted into this corner. Others were walking in and out of the room tracking paint all over the house. I just tried to find a window. :)

Comment: @TimLymington The context was the idea that all the things a person might know in the course of performing a job. But 'knowledge' didn't capture the diverse discrete nature of the bits of information and 'knowledges' was used. I was looking for an alternative.

Comment: 'Knowledges' is not unknown, but I wouldn't rate it high enough on my scale of acceptability to use it to mean bits of information that are known. I'd be more prepared to use it in the 'types of knowledge' sense; this seems a more productive semantic area for the countification of nouns. 'Coffees' and 'teas' can mean 'types of' **or** 'units (unit quantities of) [mugs etc] of', but 'wheats', 'rices', 'meats', 'furnitures', perhaps 'milks' ... can only mean 'types of'.

Comment: Knowledge is information, and information is negative entropy and is measured in Joules/Kelvin.

Comment: **Knowledges** is likely to be used only by a non-native speaker or by a certain cast of philosopher, who approaches language as if it were a LEGO® set.

Comment: Given that @Wayne_Goode did find a word, even if it had to made up by Google since they, assumable couldn't find one, I will likely grant him the 'answered' mark. 

I do also like Edwin Ashworth's comment, but without an answer I can't give him the vote.

I appreciate everyone who chimed in, at a minimum you verified that I wasn't missing the obvious and that this (a countable noun for knowledge) appears to be something of a gap in modern standard English. Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer - but my first thought was to see if the concept of **atomicity** (http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/atomism-ancient/) had been applied to knowledge, I found application in mathematics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_formula. I wonder that if language could be defined as a construction of mathematical logic then perhaps 'atom' could be a valid answer?

Comment: I have voted to close this as, 6+ years ago, the OP asked for a single word but failed to give an example sentence. In my opinion, the accepted answer is potentially valid but absent context, and as the word "knol" is vanishingly rare, EL&U cannot be assured that it is correct.

Comment: Understanding how the components of a system interrelate requires having a large amount of knowledge of different things, and can't be reduced to a single datum. The question seems misconceived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, the question is "What is the word for a bit or unit of knowledge?"  *Fact* describes a unit of a certain type of knowledge, but does not apply to all bits of knowledge.  Is a recipe a fact?  Is a surgical procedure a fact?  Is an engineering drawing a fact?  It seems there are bits or units of knowledge that are more complex than facts.

In 2007 Google invented a word, *knol* to describe a unit of knowledge more complex than a fact.  [Knol](http://knol.google.com/) was also the name of the service.  Since Google had to create a word, we can probably assume they first searched for an existing word and could not find one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "Datum". As a singular part of data, it is presumably discrete. I've seen it defined as "a single piece of information" in Merriam Webster. This seems fairly close to "discrete piece of knowledge".

Comment: Datum refers to evidence, observation. Knowledge refers to understanding or conclusions drawn thereof. So no.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is truly horrible, and not something I would ever say, except in jest. But…

> **Learning**

As in [“Top 10 key learnings from my experience in a corporate accelerator”](https://andreamarchiotto.medium.com/top-10-key-learnings-from-my-experience-in-a-corporate-accelerator-f2eaf5e4acbe).

I know. It stinks.

Answer (score 0):

Systematic jargon is commonly used in the Project Management Body of Knowledge and would break down this nomenclature of applied knowledge as either a faculty or further subclassed to a method; a faculty or faculties may be generalized as singular or plural however are typically attributed to qualitative data rather than quantitative and so wouldn’t necessarily be counted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).